# How can I make the horizontal line in ChartJS end at a specific value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chart.js

I am using ChartJS alongside the ChartJs annotation plugin. The plugin allows users to draw lines on a chart.

I am trying to draw a horizontal line on my line chart that ends at a specific value instead of extending all of the way to the end of the chart.

Here is what the chart is supposed to look like, it is the red line labeled 'Peak':

[image]

The line should end at the largest value in the data array. However right now, the horizontal line extends all of the way to the end of the chart as you can see in the fiddle below.

Here is the code for the annotation:

```
annotation: {
                drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw',
                events: ['click'],
                dblClickSpeed: 350,
                annotations: [{
                    drawTime: 'afterDraw', // overrides annotation.drawTime if set
                    id: 'a-line-1', // optional
                    type: 'line',
                    mode: 'horizontal',
                    scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
                    value: '1300',
                    borderColor: 'red',
                    borderWidth: 2,

                    // Fires when the user clicks this annotation on the chart
                    // (be sure to enable the event in the events array below).
                    onClick: function(e) {
                        // `this` is bound to the annotation element
                    }
                }]
```

Is it possible to limit the width of the line like this?

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L5069q3j/)

[ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) and [ChartJS Annotation](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation)

Comment: Hi, I am not sure I undertsand what you try to ackomplish, but altering the 'value' property of the 'annotations' will move the horizontal line. https://jsfiddle.net/a2un6p2u/

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I'm trying to get the line to end at a specific X coordinate, so it doesn't go all the way to the end of the chart. I'm trying to get it to look like the red horizontal line in the picture above where it ends at the peak of the chart and doesn't extend beyond that. My fiddle and the one you posted extend all the way across the chart. Hope that clarifies it!

Comment: I see the issue now. The problem is that such a functionality is not supported directly in the annotations so there is no easy way to implement it. What you can do though is din into the annotations source and at line 702 (model.x2 = chartArea.right;) you can play with that value to make it fit your needs.

Comment: Hi, you could use a combination of transparent 1px width "box" and transparent line (to keep the labelling, not yet available on the rectangle). fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r0dLhk2e/